# Compiling multiple contract file with web3

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js

I have a solidity file with:

```
contract X {
    // ...
    Y y;
    function X() {
       y = new Y();
    }
}

contract Y {
    // ...
}
```

But when I compile this contract using `web3.eth.compile.solidity(code);` I only get the ABI for contract Y. How do I get the ABI for each contract without putting them in seperate files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think compiling multiple contracts is supported via web3.  You'll probably want to use [solc](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity) directly for that.